# Why $\sqrt{\rho} = P \sqrt{\rho}$ in the proof of quantum error correction conditions in Nielsen & Chuang?

Tags: error-correction, linear-algebra, nielsen-and-chuang

I have trouble understanding [this proof](https://profmcruz.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/quantum-computation-and-quantum-information-nielsen-chuang.pdf#page=471) in Nielsen & Chuang, specifically the identity in $(10.20)$, which reads $$ U_k^\dagger P_k F_l \sqrt{\rho} = U_k^\dagger P_k^\dagger P_k^\dagger F_l P \sqrt{\rho}.$$

By playing around with the definitions, the only way how I would get the rightmost $P$ to appear would be by assuming $\sqrt{\rho} = P \sqrt{\rho}$. In [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6929/questions-about-theorem-and-proof-quantum-error-correction-condition-thm-10) it is stated that "$P$ is the projector onto the code space and thus does nothing to $\rho$". But I don't get this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall from the sentence immediately preceding $(10.20)$ that $\rho$ is a state in the code subspace $C$ and from the statement of theorem $10.1$ that $P$ is a projector onto $C$. We will show that $\sqrt{\rho}=P\sqrt{\rho}$.

Let $|i_L\rangle$ be an orthonormal basis of the code subspace. Then
$$
P=\sum_i|i_L\rangle\langle i_L|.\tag1
$$
Therefore, for any $|j_L\rangle$, we have$^1$
$$
P|j_L\rangle=\sum_i|i_L\rangle\langle i_L|j_L\rangle=|j_L\rangle.\tag2
$$
Now, if $\rho$ has eigendecomposition
$$
\rho=\sum_kp_k|\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k|\tag3
$$
then
$$
\sqrt{\rho}=\sum_k\sqrt{p_k}|\psi_k\rangle\langle\psi_k|.\tag4
$$
But $\rho$ is in the code subspace, so $|\psi_k\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_{ki}|i_L\rangle$ for some $\alpha_{ki}\in\mathbb{C}$. Substituting into $(4)$, we get
$$
\sqrt{\rho}=\sum_{ijk}\sqrt{p_k}\alpha_{ki}\overline{\alpha_{kj}}|i_L\rangle\langle j_L|.\tag5
$$
Finally, calculate
$$
\begin{align}
P\sqrt{\rho}&=P\sum_{ijk}\sqrt{p_k}\alpha_{ki}\overline{\alpha_{kj}}|i_L\rangle\langle j_L|\tag6\\
&=\sum_{ijk}\sqrt{p_k}\alpha_{ki}\overline{\alpha_{kj}}P|i_L\rangle\langle j_L|\tag7\\
&=\sum_{ijk}\sqrt{p_k}\alpha_{ki}\overline{\alpha_{kj}}|i_L\rangle\langle j_L|\tag8\\
&=\sqrt{\rho}\tag9
\end{align}
$$
where we used $(5)$, linearity of $P$, $(2)$, and finally $(5)$ again.

---

<sup>$^1$ Equivalently, one may take $(2)$ together with the requirement that $P$ vanishes on vectors orthogonal to the space spanned by $|i_L\rangle$ as the definition of the projector.</sup>

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\rho$ is a state *in the code*. $P$ is the projector onto the codespace. That means (by definition) that for any state $|\psi\rangle$ in the code, $P|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$.

$\rho$ is one such state (except that it's possibly mixed), so it must satisfy $P\rho=\rho$. Thus, if $\rho$ appears somewhere in an equation, you can arbitrarily choose to replace it with $P\rho$ if you want. Furthermore, if $\rho$ is in the code, all its eigenvectors are in the code. Hence $\sqrt{\rho}$, which has the same eigenvectors, must also be in the code.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't it be $P \rho P = \rho$?

Comment: That is also true. Think about a pure state $P|\psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle$. So, if I had $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, then it is true that $\rho=P\rho=\rho P=P\rho P$